# How do you list items in a list in a better layout with line breaks?

Tags: python, arrays, list, layout, printing

## Here's a simple python code:

```
random_list = ["yes", "no", "yessir", "nope", "maybe"]
print(random_list)
```

This is basics, we created a list and we printed it. The output? Well the expected output is obviously:

```
['yes', 'no', 'yessir', 'nope', 'maybe']
```

but if you agree with me, and I am sure you do, the result looks ugly. What if I want the output to look like this? :

```
yes
no
yessir
nope
maybe
```

I want to remove the brackets, the speech marks, and I want the list to use line breaks like: \n

## You could do this:

```
print(random_list[0])
print(random_list[1])
print(random_list[2])
print(random_list[3])
print(random_list[4])
```

But what if the list is extremely long, or you simply do not KNOW how long it is? I am sure you can use len() and 'for' loops to do something, but I can not remember... If you know a way to list the items in this better layout, I will definitely appreciate it. I am not new to python, but I always get mixed up. If you have some advanced methods like using lambda or something, you can share it too. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate was first google result for "python print list on seperate lines"

Answer (score 2):

Put a newline between all elements:

```
print("\n".join(random_list))
```

Or, to be more robust with regard to the types inside the list:

```
print("\n".join(map(str, random_list)))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for a list of ints, or indeed anything but strings

Comment: The example contained only strings, but you could do a conversion: `print("\n".join(map(str, random_list)))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with for loops:

```
for item in random_list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: The list comprehension is not the best solution. There's no need to create a list containing only elements with the value `None` and then throw that list away.

Comment: I suppose so. The for loop is better

Comment: I think for this particular problem the second option is not very nice. Sure it will work, but it will be confusing on why using a list comprehension if we are not creating a list. two lines are sometimes better than one.